# Show time in different time zones

Tags: time-date

I take a lot of different MOOC and each class declare own deadline relative to some time zone.

Are there any Emacs mode that show date/time in buffer for several selected time zones in same time?

I expect that mode should understand usual time zone names like `UTC+2`, `EET`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations

Also mode should display time in different formats (ISO and American AM/PM). I miss one deadline on half hour just because I didn't know what is `12:59 AM` (I think it should be at noon but actually it on deep night).

Answer (score 6):

I start typing different keywords in <kbd>M-x</kbd> and see completion to:

```
display-time-world
```

That is mostly what I look for:

```
display-time-world is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
`time.el'.

(display-time-world)

Enable updating display of times in various time zones.
`display-time-world-list' specifies the zones.
To turn off the world time display, go to that window and type `q'.
```

Unfortunately `display-time-world-list` is an alist `(TIMEZONE LABEL)` and TIMEZONE should be in a format **supported by your system**.

There is `timezone-world-timezones`. Docs for that variable correctly states that TZ abbreviations are ambiguous (same abbreviation was used for different offsets).

With:

```
(mapc (lambda (el) (add-to-list 'display-time-world-list el))
      '(("EET" "EET")
        ("PST" "PST")))
```

I have first part of requested. Unfortunately `%p` formater (for AM/PM) always empty.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for `display-time-world-time-format`. My setting is:

```
(setq display-time-world-time-format "%Z\t%a %d %b %R")
```

And the output of display-time-world is some like this:

```
Sydney    AEST  Fri 28 Jul 20:27
```

That's 24-hour format

Answer (score 2):

`display-time-world` is will be deprecated in favour of `world-clock` in the upcoming release, Emacs 28.

Similarly, the configuration variables will also be renamed:

- `display-time-world-list` --> `world-clock-list`
- `display-time-world-time-format` --> `world-clock-time-format`

One example configuration would then be this:

```lisp
  (setq world-clock-list
    '(
      ("Australia/Melbourne" "Melbourne")
      ("Asia/Calcutta" "India")
      ("America/Chicago" "Chicago")
      ("Asia/Kathmandu" "Kathmandu")
      ("Etc/UTC" "UTC")))

  (setq world-clock-time-format "%a, %d %b %I:%M %p %Z")
```

Comment: Emacs 28 has not been released. The latest release is Emacs 27.2.