# Get time in AM/PM format

Tags: time-date

`(format-time-string "%p")` is empty in my Emacs. How I can format date in AM/PM format?

That answer second part of [Show time in different time zones](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20799/show-time-in-different-time-zones)

**UPDATE**

```
(length (format-time-string "%p"))  ; is 0
(getenv "LC_TIME")                  ; is "en_DK.utf8"
```

My default preferences (in `.emacs`):

```
(setq display-time-24hr-format t)
(setq display-time-day-and-date nil)
```

Comment: The documentation says that %p is the locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM. So I suspect the problem is with the `en_DK` locale on your machine. You could try the command `date +%p` in a terminal window. Does it match what you see in emacs? (Make sure that the locale matches when you test.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`format-time-string` requires a format together with an actual time to format.  So you want to write something like

```
(format-time-string "%p" (current-time))
```

which at the moment outputs `am` for me.  Similarly

```
(format-time-string "%l:%M %p" (current-time))
```

currently gives `9:40 am`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Locales section in Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Locales.html), the `format-time-string` function is influenced by the system locale configuration. Moreover, [the function docstring](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/format-time-string) says "%p is the **locale’s** equivalent of either AM or PM.".

Because of these tips, I wrote the following code to changed the locale temporarily before using the format function:

```el
(let ((system-time-locale "en_US.UTF-8"))
  (format-time-string "%r %p" (current-time)))
```

After some tries at the scratch buffer, it seems that using the "en_US.UTF-8" locale prints the "PM"/"AM". These are the results after executing each sexp with <kbd>C-j</kbd> (`eval-print-last-sexp`):

```el
(let ((system-time-locale "en_US.UTF-8"))
  (format-time-string "%r %p" (current-time)))
"01:21:33 PM PM"

(let ((system-time-locale "en_DK.UTF-8"))
  (format-time-string "%r %p" (current-time)))
"01:21:55  "

(let ((system-time-locale "en_UK.UTF-8"))
  (format-time-string "%r %p" (current-time)))
"01:22:14  "
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the emacs manual there is this page: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Time-Display-Format.html. that talks about changing the time format.

The following code should do what you want if I understand correctly.

```
(setq display-time-24hr-format nil)
(setq display-time-string-forms
      '(12-hours ":" minutes am-pm))
```

Comment: How your suggestion can be applied to `(format-time-string "%p")` without altering global settings?

Comment: Well I guess I don't know exactly what you mean by it being empty. Would you be able to add something like this:

`(format-time-string (concat "Start of string   " (if (>= (string-to-number (substring (current-time-string (current-time)) 11 13)) 12) "PM" "AM") "   end of string"))`